# How do i solve this system : $\operatorname{lcm}(a,b)=8160, \gcd(a,b)=5$? with integers $a, b >5 $?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm, least-common-multiple

let integers  $a, b >5 $ such that $\operatorname{lcm}(a,b)=8160, \gcd(a,b)=5$ , I have tried out to use $\operatorname{lcm} (a,b)\cdot \gcd(a,b)$ to get $a.b$ and putting $a=d a', b =db'$ with $(a',b')=1$ then $d^2\mid40800$ , then it must to set all quadratic divisors which divide $40800$ , now  how do I complet the solution to determine the pair$(a',b')$  or by other method ?

Answer (score 0):

$8160 = 2^5\cdot3\cdot 5\cdot 17$

$\gcd(a,b) = 5$

How can you pair the necessary factors that fit the criteria?

if both $a,b> 5$ then $a = 2^5\cdot 5\cdot 17, b = 3\cdot 5$ is one solution
$a = 2^5\cdot 5, b = 3\cdot 5\cdot 17$ is another and $(a,b)=(85,480) $

Comment: $8160$ is divisible by 17.

Comment: duh... thanks.  will fix

Comment: what about (85,480) ?

Comment: I did not mean to suggest that I had exhausted all of the combinations of prime factors.

Comment: but the question to determine all pairs , may i'm wrong

Comment: I have shown that the solution set is small. I don't need to find all pairs.  I am just trying to point you in the right direction.

Comment: Ah, ok thanks for that